# connect to Neo4j through Android - impossible task?

Tags: java, android, neo4j, httpurlconnection

Is there any way I can connect to a remote Neo4j server from an Android Project **at all** ? I have used several approaches: JDBC driver and through REST API using Jersey Client however none of these approaches are successful. All of these work in a pure Java project but fail miserably in Android. At this stage I lost hope that there exists a way I can talk to the database through android. Is that feasible or am I wasting my time trying to find impossible solution ?

Comment: Can you post more details on the error you are getting? Looks like it could be a classpath/missing jar issue.

Comment: Jersey may not be supported in Android.  But at an absolute minimum, you should be able to use the REST API and parse the JSON some other way.

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede is there any way I can connect then, using pure android ?

Comment: I'd investigate why Jersey isn't working for you.  A quick search turned up some pages that say it's not supported on Android, but maybe that's changed.  If you end up rolling your own solution, just search for general info about making HTTP requests and parsing JSON on Android.  There's nothing really Neo4j-specific about it.

Answer (score 1):

If Neo4j exposes an HTTP REST interface, then yes of course you can access it from Android. There are many different ways, including `HTTPUrlConnection` and Apache `HttpClient`.

If you want to use Jersey, there's no reason why that wouldn't work. I'd start with one of the above first though to prove to yourself that the basics work.

Here someone as written a Java binding to the REST API.

> https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding

You can use (most) Java libraries in Android.