# delete external library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

how can I delete an external library from Android Project using Android Studio ? In my gradle script I  have :

```
def neo4jVersion = "2.1.7"
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
   compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:${neo4jVersion}"
}
```

This is pulling about 15 jars but I need to delete one of them, each time I do it, it deletes it but when I run the project again it reappears ! How to delete it permanently ? This is screenshot

[image]

Comment: "I need to delete one of them" -- why? Presumably `neoj` will fail if it does not have that library, in which case you may as well just get rid of all of `neoj`.

Comment: When i run the app it's giving me error:  trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class": ll-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.   I read that removing the library might solve it

Comment: Have you confirmed that `neoj` works on Android at all?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do and use REST java binding, I asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552810/connect-to-neo4j-through-android-impossible-task

Comment: these are dependencies for the package you are including. they are pulled when resolving the `compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:${neo4jVersion}"`  line. Unless you include the jars directly yourself, there is no way around that.

Comment: so you can do that: take all the jars except the one you don't want, put them into libs, link the libs dir in your gradle file, remove the `compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:${neo4jVersion}"` line. (but that will probably not work as dependencies are usually here for a reason.)

Comment: Or try `exclude` to block this dependency in Gradle. I have no idea whether `neoj` can survive that or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `geronimo` library is the dependency of the `Neo4j kernel`.
You can't get rid of it without messing up the whole library.